# How to allow non-root access to /dev/tty7

Tags: image, user, fbi

I have problems running fbi without sudo. As user pi running

```
fbi -noverbose -nocomments -T 7 -1 -t 10  test.jpg
or
fbi -noverbose -nocomments -T 1 -1 -t 10 test.jpg
```

I get an error /dev/tty7: Permission denied.

tty1 and tty7 belong to group tty.

```
crw--w---- 1 root tty       4,  7 huhti 13 07:01 tty7
```

I have added user pi to groups tty and video.

```
sudo usermod -a -G tty pi
sudo usermod -a -G video pi
```

Comment: tty group has no read permission

Comment: I added read permission `crw-rw---- 1 root tty`. Now theres no error but nothing is displayed. fb0 has also read and write permissions.

Comment: "Now theres no error but nothing is displayed." Cross-check with sudo, do you get the same response with same command plus sudo, or not?

Comment: With sudo I get same information in console than without sudo but with sudo image is displayed.

Comment: "With sudo I get same information in console than without sudo but with sudo image is displayed." Do you mean you get the image displayed and "Permission denied" if you run `sudo fbi -noverbose -nocomments -T 7 -1 -t 10  test.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be even more confusing in Raspbian than in *nix in general (and perhaps more confusing than it need be), but try this:

> sudo raspi-config

go to `5 Interfacing Options`

go to `P6 Serial`

select `Yes`

raspi-config responds:

> The serial login shell is enabled
>
> The serial interface is enabled

When asked if you want to reboot, answer `Yes`. Hope this helps; I can't test it on my RPi because it's headless.

Comment: Thanks but that did not help. fbi behaves like without those settings.

Comment: So sorry... I'd try it on mine if it were connected to a monitor, but please follow up here when you solve it; the information will help someone else.